# Creating HTML table from Json URL

Tags: javascript, html, json, xml

I need support for creating a table  generated from this Json url: " https://search.lib.ou.ac.lk/cgi-bin/koha/svc/report?id=629 " [try this](https://search.lib.ou.ac.lk/cgi-bin/koha/svc/report?id=629) .

> The data generated this format: [[167208,"8170002583","Information technology in libraries"],[167215,"9556070346","Impediments to regional economic cooperation in South Asia"],[167190,"9789553038630","Jene Booster"],

The Structure: | biblionumber | isbn | title

I try this code but it does not work. Please help.

```
  const requestJSON = async url => {
  const response = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  biblionumber.innerHTML = response.squadName;
  isbn.innerHTML = response.homeTown;
  title.innerHTML = response.formed;
  } requestJSON(requestUrl);
type here
```

I need to display date into html table

Comment: why the `perl` tag? are you using it somewhere?

Comment: The URL result  generated from Perl script but i need to display with in html.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const jsonData = [
    [167157, "9786249966901", "சொல்லும் செய்திகள்"],
    [167116, "9798188689179", "Principles of cosmology and gravitation"],
    [167162, "9780748636297", "Practice-led research, research-led practice in the creative arts"],
    [167182, "9559896709", "තොරතුරු සාක්ෂරතාවය"],
    [167125, "9789556441185", "Airborne laser scanning : "],
    [167127, "9789556441109", "Fundamental theories of spatial data and GIS"],
    [167222, "9780415670777", "Dramatherapy with children, young people and schools : enabling creativity, sociability, communication and learning"],
    [42899, "9789559588597", "Human resource managment"],
    [167159, "9780702081545", "Aulton's pharmaceutics : "],
    [167166, "9789553067906", "A view from the international maritime boundary line : "],
    [167141, "9789556441086", "සහභාගිත්ව ප්‍රවේශ ක්‍රමවේද "],
    [167133, "9789556441031", "Cattle diseases"],
    [167212, "9789551359065", "National conference of university librarians association of Sri Lanka (NACULA 2017) : "],
    [167181, "9789555531559", "ජනසන්නිවේදනයේ අත්පොත "],
    [167120, "9780876590683", "The giant encyclopedia of lesson plans :"],
    [167111, "9789555051507", "ශ්‍රී ලංකාවේ සමයාන්තර ප්‍රයාණය පිලිබඳ ශාස්ත්‍රීය අධ්‍යයනයක් (1960 සිට 2005) "],
    [167196, "9780749411497", "Using communications media in open and flexible learning"],
    [167113, "9780071629980", "Intermediate algebra "],
    [167171, "9780140714852", "The Tempest"],
    [78894, "9789558383766", "ජාතිත පුස්තකාල"],
    [167192, "9780749408138", "Exploring open and distance learning"],
    [167180, "955951153X", "රාජරතනාකාරය හෙවත් විජය රජු පටන් වීරවික්‍රම රජු දක්වා ලංකා ඉතිහාසය"],
    [167131, "9789556441246", "දේශීය සහ විදේශීය වෙළඳපොළ සඳහා වැදගත් කැපුම් මල් සහ විසිතුරු පත්‍රික ශාක නිෂ්පාදනය"],
    [167221, "9781462535316", "Executive skills in children and adolescents : "],
    [164248, "9786245873203", "College house  : The cradle of Sri Lanka's university education"],
    [167137, "9789556440997", "Sri Lankan war literature : "],
    [167118, "0134484983", "Hydropower engineering "],
    [167126, "9789556441055", "Evolution of measurement units and fundamental concepts of Metrology"],
    [74936, "9780071332736", "The macro economy today /"],
    [148997, "9556101055", "The monk and the peasant :"]
];

const generateHTMLTable = (jsonData) => {
    const table = document.createElement('table');
    const thead = document.createElement('thead');
    const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    const headers = ['Biblionumber', 'ISBN', 'Title'];
    const headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
    headers.forEach(headerText => {
        const th = document.createElement('th');
        th.textContent = headerText;
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
    });
    thead.appendChild(headerRow);
    table.appendChild(thead);

    jsonData.forEach(bookData => {
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        bookData.forEach(cellData => {
            const cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.textContent = cellData;
            row.appendChild(cell);
        });
        tbody.appendChild(row);
    });
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    return table;
};

const jsonDataHTML = generateHTMLTable(jsonData);
document.body.appendChild(jsonDataHTML);
```

Here I am assuming that you can get the desired JSON from the URL given above.

If yes, to display it in an HTML table:

```
const generateHTMLTable = (jsonData) => {
    const table = document.createElement('table');
    const thead = document.createElement('thead');
    const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    const headers = ['Biblionumber', 'ISBN', 'Title'];
    const headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
    headers.forEach(headerText => {
        const th = document.createElement('th');
        th.textContent = headerText;
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
    });
    thead.appendChild(headerRow);
    table.appendChild(thead);

    jsonData.forEach(bookData => {
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        bookData.forEach(cellData => {
            const cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.textContent = cellData;
            row.appendChild(cell);
        });
        tbody.appendChild(row);
    });
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    return table;
};

const jsonDataHTML = generateHTMLTable(jsonData);
document.body.appendChild(jsonDataHTML);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sachithw/52vhpfm0/2/

Comment: I need to use URL rather dataset - read data itself because data  set is dynamic. data change every time when use the URL( it show last 30 days ' entered data set').

Comment: @Bala Simply call the API to retrieve the data, then create a method and pass the dataset to it. Within that method, the functionality should be above. Simple